# SHA 256 custom key

Tags: c++, cryptography, hmac, sha256

The following code is a test for sha 256. Where it generates a hmac based on the message and the key. But in the below example the key is generated at random whereas my project demands me to give my own key, can anybody please tell me how to go about it. Thanks.

```
AutoSeededRandomPool prng;

SecByteBlock key(16);
prng.GenerateBlock(key, key.size());

string plain = "HMAC Test";
string mac, encoded;

/*********************************\
\*********************************/

// Pretty print key
encoded.clear();
StringSource(key, key.size(), true,
new HexEncoder(
        new StringSink(encoded)
    ) // HexEncoder
); // StringSource

cout << "key: " << encoded << endl;
cout << "plain text: " << plain << endl;

/*********************************\
\*********************************/

try
{
    HMAC< SHA256 > hmac(key, key.size());

    StringSource(plain, true, 
        new HashFilter(hmac,
            new StringSink(mac)
        ) // HashFilter      
    ); // StringSource
}
catch(const CryptoPP::Exception& e)
{
     cerr << e.what() << endl;
     exit(1);
}

/*********************************\
\*********************************/

// Pretty print
encoded.clear();
StringSource(mac, true,
    new HexEncoder(
        new StringSink(encoded)
    ) // HexEncoder
); // StringSource

cout << "hmac: " << encoded << endl;
```

Comment: you have to use a 16 bytes block

Comment: that means should change the type of the key ?? IF so can you please tell me how to do this. Thanks

Comment: from SecByteBlock key(16); I suppose key is 16 bytes size, so take something 16 bytes long ( in example uint16_t), initialize this with some data (i.e 12345)